# Can you call CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation from a CLLocationManagerDelegate response?

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm in a monitored region. When I exit it didExitRegion: gets called to my . Inside of that response, can I activate startUpdatingLocation for specific location tracking?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Provided you satisfy all the conditions required for startUpdatingLocation to work normally, it will work the same if you call it inside didExitRegion.